# Can you identify this blood-like font?

Tags: font-identification

[image: Sample of font text]

Hello,
Can you give me an identification of this font? Which font is that?
I've looked through Blambot / Whatfontis / WhatTheFont / Identifont but haven't got any of its name.
Thanks for helping out with that.

I've seen this font in Gaia webcomic here: http://www.sandraandwoo.com/gaia/comics/2015-02-03-breaking-all-barriers-043.jpg

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a modification of Bucket of Blood font, rasterized and then the holes and clots are made manually, so there is no official font for it...hope this clear things up.

Comment: There is an italic version of it, as can be seen here http://www.fonts.com/font/blambot/bucket-o-blood/bb-complete-family-pack. I also use free transform tool, so maybe it slanted more than usual...

Comment: Thanks, Powree, haven't actually expected to see you here. :D I was thinking about Bucket of Blood font but never thought that it got rasterized. Much further successes with Gaia and other webcomics!